# Beautiful way to check if collection has only one element

Tags: kotlin

Is there any way to check if my collection has one and only one element?

```
if (myCollection.size == 1){

}
```

something like

```
if (myCollection.isSingle()){

}
```

**UPD:** I liked the `isSingle()` naming from the proposed answer.

Thanks

Comment: what's wrong with `myCollection.size == 1`?

Comment: @IR42 when you code in a more functional style the motivation is to use more functions in a declarative way and less imperative code and explicit control flow. It is believed that doing the former you are less prone to bugs given you are expected to reuse already tested functions.

Comment: @IR42 I just want my code to shine :)

Answer (score 6):

Kotlin already has two methods for this:

```
fun <T> Iterable<T>.single(): T
```

Returns the single element, or throws an exception if the collection is empty or has more than one element.

```
fun <T> Iterable<T>.singleOrNull(): T?
```

Returns single element, or null if the collection is empty or has more than one element.

Using the second option you can replace `if` with the `let` function

```
listOf(1).singleOrNull()?.let { print(it) }
```

Comment: I like the let funtion use, but what if I also need else condition?

Comment: `listOf<Int>().singleOrNull()?.let { print(it) } ?: print("Elvis operator will execute this if left expression returns null")`

Comment: works fine only with if branch. Elvis operators are unreadable. Thanks!

Comment: @nutella_eater they are quite readable if you format the code properly, e.g.: https://gist.github.com/1gravity/7ddbdcd7294d5132afe34460fbefd406

Answer (score 2):

Why not create one? Maybe it is not what you are looking for (some walkaround), but you can try to go with extension functions. If you check it many times - it could improve readability.

```
fun <T> Collection<T>.isSingle(): Boolean = size == 1
```

Then you can call it this way:

```
listOf("asd", "qwe").isSingle()  // false
listOf("asd").isSingle()         // true
```

Comment: The Kotlin standard library already has [an extension on `Iterable<T>` with the same name](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/single.html), so it would be not intuitive that one of them checks the size and the other returns the single element or throws an exception. Also, see [`singleOrNulll`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/single-or-null.html) which may be suitable here without a custom extension.

Comment: Agree, changed it to isSingle(). Still in my opinion, if there are many "isSingle" conditions, and after that, we do not do anything with the list - it could work. If the condition determines the list state - we could use singleOrNull()?.let { it.someOperations()} witch could be better.

Comment: I don't like the idea of making an extension for such a tiny case. In large projects it can be lost and forgotten, so other devs don't have a clue that this function exists.

Comment: This ext. function could be created even for a single class file if we need it. if you use this list.size() == 1 more than 4-5 maybe i would go this way